# How to aggregate sum over multiple date ranges in query set?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

Is it possible to annotate `.sum()`s over multiple date ranges in one `QuerySet`

Ie, basically combining these, so each object has the sum for each date range.

```
query_set_week = DailyReports.objects.filter(
    date__range=('2018-08-27', '2018-08-31')) \
        .select_related('profile') \
        .values('profile__user_id') \
        .annotate(premium=Sum('total_field'),
            first_name=F('profile__user__first_name'),
            last_name=F('profile__user__last_name') \
        .order_by('profile__agent_code')


query_set_year = DailyReports.objects.filter(
    date__range=('2018-01-01', '2018-08-31')) \
        .select_related('profile') \
        .values('profile__user_id') \
        .annotate(premium=Sum('total_field'),
            first_name=F('profile__user__first_name'),
            last_name=F('profile__user__last_name') \
        .order_by('profile__agent_code')
```

Both work individually, but it's difficult to loop through and display the data (user - week total - year total, for example), because someone may have a result in the year filter, but not in the week filter.

Edit: I'm currently able to accomplish my goal using `.raw()` with a massive SQL statement, but I figured there was a more Pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want more than one row, you could [union two querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union) like so:

```
base_qs = DailyReports.objects \
        .select_related('profile') \
        .values('profile__user_id') \
        .annotate(premium=Sum('total_field'),
            first_name=F('profile__user__first_name'),
            last_name=F('profile__user__last_name') \
        .order_by('profile__agent_code')

query_set_week = base_qs.filter(date__range=('2018-08-27', '2018-08-31'))
query_set_year = base_qs.filter(date__range=('2018-01-01', '2018-08-31'))

query_set_week_and_year = query_set_week.union(query_set_year)
```

`query_set_week_and_year` should give you two rows, by only executing one SQL query!

---

#### What's happening here?

Most importantly django does not execute any SQL until a queryset is evaluated (e.g. iterated over, `list()`-ed, `len()`-ed, [and so on](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)). So we are just constructing SQL, not executing what looks like 4 queries!

Most databases (even sqlite, I think) has some query optimization. I.e. it will see things that are repeated in the two queries and do that bit first (In a way that the code *appears* to be doing). So we should be doing this in (near enough) the most efficient way.

---

So it shouldn't be too time-intensive and I think provides some readable code(?)!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it seems you've got two almost-identical queries that only differ by the `date__range`. Why not try using a SQL `OR` on the date range using the [`Q`-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

You can attempt the following:

```
query_set_week_and_year = DailyReports.objects \
    .filter(
        Q(date__range=('2018-08-27', '2018-08-31')) | Q(date__range=('2018-01-01', '2018-08-31')) \
    ).select_related('profile') \
    .values('profile__user_id') \
    .annotate(
        premium=Sum('total_field'),
        first_name=F('profile__user__first_name'),
        last_name=F('profile__user__last_name'
    ).order_by('profile__agent_code')
```

---

#### Q-objects in a nutshell

Q objects let you apply `AND` and `OR` filter conditions via the binary `&` and `|` operators. (But you only really need them for the `OR` operation as `AND` is handled by a comma in the filter function)

For example finding all users that have a firstname or lastname that begins with 'A':

```
User.objects.filter(Q(firstname__startswith='A') | Q(lastname__startswith='A'))
```

---

#### Side note

It seems line one date__range is contained in the other: `2018-08-27`-->`2018-08-31` is within `2018-01-01`-->`2018-08-31`. If these are the two date ranges you care about, then all you need is the second query..?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! However, I'm attempting to separately display totals over a week and a year period, instead of getting all data from both ranges combined.

Comment: Ohh so like a week-by-week total?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but that'd actually be extremely useful! I was thinking more display YTD, QTD, Current Week totals all at once, by querying respective date ranges.

Comment: Haha, right I think I get what you mean! In one query, you want go to get 2 rows returned? First row is the yearly total and second row is the monthly/quarterly total?

Comment: Right! So I could loop through the objects and show `user - yearly total - monthly total - etc`.

Comment: I think I have you, but please keep the dialogue. It's rather fun trying to solve this!